# AWS Mobile Analytics custom event attribute and metric naming convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I've seem multiple references to using prefixed attribute & metric names (a_, m_). Is this necessary or does Redshift do this automatically when auto exporting? Am I ok with leaving out the `a_` & `m_`

```
'CUSTOM EVENT NAME', {
    'a_Attr_1': 'ATTRIBUTE_1_VALUE',
    'a_Attr_2': 'ATTRIBUTE_2_VALUE'
    /* ... */
}, {
    'm_METRIC_1': 1,
    'm_METRIC_2': 99.3
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is added automatically by Amazon Mobile Analytics Auto-Export.

It signifies event attributes or metrics.
You should not add it yourself.

More information and detail can be found in the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/auto-export.html